# Bson pretty print using Java MongoDb driver

Tags: java, mongodb, bson, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

I am using the Mongo Aggregation Framework using the Java MongoDB driver, version 3.3. I have an *aggregagtion pipeline*, that is merely collection of type `List<Bson>`. I am trying to find a way to pretty print each stage of the pipeline.

Calling the `toString` method on each element is not sufficient, because each stages is an instance of a simple implementation of the `Bson` interface, which is `SimplePipelineStage`. This stupid class has not any override of the `toString` method.

The pipeline is created using factory methods of mongo java driver `Aggregates` class, like the following:

```
Aggregates.match(/* ... */)
Aggregates.project(/* ... */)
// And so on...
```

Javadoc can be found [here](http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.3/?com/mongodb/client/model/Aggregates.html).

How can I pretty print such objects? I know for sure that the type `BasicDbObject` has a smart `toString` implementation, but I cannot find a way to convert from `Bson` to `BasicDbObject`.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `.toJson()` It's actually a method

Comment: `toJson` is not define on `Bson` type. Please, read the question, first

Comment: Sorry was thinking of `Document`, which you really should be using anyway. I personally pump pipeline debugging through Gson. So I could find a code block somewhere.

Comment: I am using `Aggregates` factory methods to create each pipelines. It is not my choice to use an abstract `Bson` :)

Comment: Can you show the actual code constructing the pipeline please. It would be useful to see exactly what you are using so you can be pointed to the correct place.

Comment: Nothing special, but I updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: What do you actually mean by that? Something like `match = Aggregates.match(/* ... */)` or directly into a list `pipeline = Arrays.asList(Aggregates.match(/* ... */), Aggregates.project(/* ... */))` ? It's kind of why you where asked to show an actual block of code, so we can see the actual context. You aren't really telling us much in your question.

Comment: I found a solution: have a look to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/peeL8wIWxwA) link

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Googling a bit harder, I found a solution to pretty print a `Bson` instance. The trick is to convert it into an instance of `BsonDocument`, which has an implementation of the `toString` method that returns the string representation of the corresponding JSON.

```
Bson bson = Filters.gt("a", 10);
BsonDocument bsonDocument = bson.toBsonDocument(BsonDocument.class, MongoClient.DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY);
System.out.println(bsonDocument);
```

The original link is the following: [Converting Bson object to BsonDocument](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/peeL8wIWxwA).

Answer (score 4):

This is a rather old question, however I put my suggestion (for mongodb-driver 3.6.4) here as this is the most relevant post when googling on "mongodb java driver pretty print":

```
BsonDocument bsonDocument = bson.toBsonDocument(BsonDocument.class, MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry());
JsonWriterSettings.Builder settingsBuilder = JsonWriterSettings.builder().indent(true);
System.out.println(bsonDocument.toJson(settingsBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 2):

With the mongo 4 driver it looks something like this:

```java
    private String pretty(Document document) {
        var settings = JsonWriterSettings.builder()
                .indent(true)
                .outputMode(JsonMode.SHELL)
                .build();
        return document.toJson(settings);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For mongodb-java API 3.4, the constant `MongoClient.DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY` is no more accessible directly, it's a private member. There is a static method `CodecRegistry getDefaultCodecRegistry()` which returns the same constant.

Another point, `BsonDocument.toString()` internally does a `toJson()` with default `JsonWriterSettings`. In order to see the Shell equivalent of Query, use it like below:

```
public void logQuery(Bson filter) {
    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {

        LOGGER.debug(
                "filter query: " + filter.toBsonDocument(BsonDocument.class, MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry())
                        .toJson(new JsonWriterSettings(JsonMode.SHELL)));
    }
}
```